# How do I make the connection permanent with Network-Manager?

Tags: network-manager

```
(1) I installed Ubuntu minimal with an ethernet cable.
(2) sudo apt install --no-install-recommends network-manager
(3) sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service 
    sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
(4) nmcli d wifi connect my_wifi password <password>
```

Connection establishes..but at boot sometimes it does and sometime it does not!! what's wrong ?

Comment: I installed ubuntu minimal with an ethernet cable, installed network manager then tried to get the wifi working...but the wifi connection randomly gets established. when I sleep and then resume the connection establishes!! could it be that the ethernet connection is interfering with the wireless ? if so, how do I disable the ethernet connection ?

Comment: Do I have to install dhcpcd in addition to network manager ?

Comment: Seemingly random wireless connections and disconnections are often due to weak wireless signal or interfering stations on the same channel. Your wireless stack, regardless of whether you use Network Manager or not, is designed to keep connections alive when possible. (Who would want a system that is *designed* to be unreliable?)